# General form of parabola using equation of Tangent at Vertex and Axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I had read in my notes that the equation of parabola can be given by

(Equation of axis)$^2$ = (Length of Latus rectum)*(Equation of tangent at vertex)

(I don't know the systematic proof. Is there something I am missing in the equation?)

Now take look at this very basic equation of a parabola

$ y^2=4ax $

Here the equation of axis of parabola is $(y=0)$ and that of tangent at vertex is $(x=0)$

I can also write the equation of axis as $(ny=0)$ and tangent at vertex as $(mx=0)$
(where m and n are constants)

And hence using the first equation I can write the equation of parabola as

$(ny)^2 = 4a(mx)$

which gives me a completely different parabola.
I don't know where I have gone wrong. Please guide me.

Comment: **When** $a^2+b^2=1$ and the line $ax+by+c=0$ is the axis of a parabola then its tangent at the vertex is perpendicular to it, say $bx−ay+d=0$. And an equation of the parabola is $$(ax+by+c)^2=4p(bx−ay+d).$$

Comment: Oh I see what I was missing there... But still don't understand why we need that condition a^2+b^2=1.

Comment: It comes from $y^2=4px$ (orthonormally) rotated and translated to a general parabola.

Comment: Take a look at this parabola.   (2x - y - 3)^2  = -20(x + 2y - 4). It doesn't satisfy the condition but represents a parabola with the given lines as its axis and tangent at vertex.

Comment: You can rewrite it: $5(\frac{2x-y-3}{\sqrt{5}})^2=-20\sqrt{5}\frac{(x+2y-4)}{\sqrt{5}}$ i.e. $(\frac{2x-y-3}{\sqrt{5}})^2=-4\sqrt{5}\frac{(x+2y-4)}{\sqrt{5}}$ and identify $p$. By the way it is also $$5\,\left(-\left({{2\,y}\over{\sqrt{5}}}+{{x}\over{\sqrt{5}}}-{{9
 }\over{\sqrt{5}}}\right)^2+\left(y+1\right)^2+\left(x-1\right)^2
 \right)$$ making $(1,-1)$ the focus and $x+2y-9$ the directrix.

Comment: @AspiringEngineer  $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the norm of both the normal and the directional vectors $(a,b), (b,-a).$ To have a uniquely defined parabola, the vectors are normalized (they are considered with norm 1).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have good knowledge of vectors. I already figured it out via help of Jan Magnus. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 2):

Here, it is not equation of axis, it is perpendicular distance of any random point on parabola say (h,k) from axis and also perpendicular distance from vertex and not equation of vertex
So for general equation
Perpendicular distance from axis of point (h,k) is k and from vertex, it's h
So equation will be:

k²=4ah

Replacing h with x and k with y, we get equation of parabola
y²=4ax