# Find an equation of a rotated parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Given a line $y=kx$ on a Cartesian coordinate, I want to find an equation of a parabola, whose base is on that line at point $(x_1,y_1)$ and passes through point $(x_2,y_2)$.

Then, an equation of a red line that is perpendicular to line $y=kx$ at point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $y=-\frac{1}{k}x+y_1+\frac{1}{k}x_1$. I tried to assume that $y=kx$ line is my new $x$ axis, and $y=-\frac{1}{k}x+y_1+\frac{1}{k}x_1$ is my new $y$ axis and do calculations, but the computation became messy and I couldn't finish. Is there simple way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the parabola to have y=kx as its tangent at vertex?

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180898/axes-based-equations-of-conics), we can write the equation of a parabola as
$$d_{\text{Axis}}^2=4a\cdot d_{\text{Tangent at vertex}}.$$
Here $d_{\text{line}}$ represents the algebraic distance of any arbitrary point on the parabola from the said line. $**$(*More intuitive explanation below*).

---

Here, tangent at vertex is $y=kx$.

 The axis (straight line through the vertex (that you referred to as the base) and perpendicular to tangent at vertex) is $y+\dfrac xk=y_1+\dfrac{x_1}{k}$.

Thus the equation of parabola is $$\bigg(\frac{ky+x-(ky_1+x_1)}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\bigg)^2=4a\cdot\dfrac{y-kx}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$$

Put $(x_2, y_2)$ into the equation and find $a$. Done :)

---

---

$**$ Intuitive explanation: Consider the standard parabola $y^2=4ax$. Here $y$= Distance from X axis ($\equiv$ Axis) and $x$= Distance from Y axis ($\equiv $ Tangent at vertex)

Answer (score 0):

$x_1$ and $y_1$ make the problem complicate. First, we do a translation to make $x_1, y_1$ move to origin in $x'-y'$ coordinate system.

Now, the parabola touch $y=kx$ at origin and pass $(x'_0,y'_0)$ where $x'_0=x_2-x_1, y'_0=y_2-y_1$.

Then we make a rotation to $x''-y''$ coordinate system. by a rotation of $\theta$.

$x'=x''\cos\theta + y''\sin\theta$

$y'=-x''\sin\theta + y''\cos\theta$ (Hope I did not rotation at wrong direction).

$(x'_0,y'_0)$ now rotated to $(x''_0,y''_0)$.

Then the parabola touch x-axis at origin.

The parabola is $y''=ax''^2$. Put $(x''_0,y''_0)$ into the equation, you can solve for $a$ and fix the parameter of parabola equation in $x''-y''$ coordinate. Then you can work back to a equation in $x-y$ coordinate. The equation could be complicated so you can write it in terms of $a$ since you already have the expression of $a$.

Method II:
Start from general equation of parabola:
$\frac{(ax+by+c)^2}{a^2+b^2}=(x-x_f)^2+(y-y_f)^2$

Assume the signed distance between focus $(x_f,y_f)$ to $y=kx$ is $d$. Then you can write down the equation of directrix $ax+by+c$ and focus $(x_f,y_f)$ in term of $d$. Then put $(x_2,y_2)$ into the equation, you can find $d$ and then fix all parameters $a,b,c,x_f,y_f$.

Comment: Method II looks simpler, hope it answer your question.